# iphone 3d library with physics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, 3d, game-physics

are there any light 3d iphone libraries that have:

- Physics ( ragdoll physics )
- 3D scene graph
- Advanced lighting
- Ability to import 3D model from blender, 3d studio max, etc.

it should preferably be mature and have no bugs.
i have seen cocos3d but many say it is riddled with bugs.

it also must be below $400 USD

Comment: This is probably better suited for [gamedev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you thought about `unity3d`?

Comment: yes it's a bit expensive though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, there's ofcourse the [Unreal Engine](http://udk.com/). Since it's feature-rich enough to create infinity blade, it will probably suffice for most.

Licensing for software that's distributed to a third party is $99 up-front, and a 25% royalty for all revenue above $50.000 . If the total revenue is less than $50.000, the license fee is limited to $99. There are different fees for in-house applications.

However: IANAL; [see for yourself](http://udk.com/licensing) whether the terms and conditions are acceptable for your use.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [Oolong Engine](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: it seems to barely have any shading